# NVMe disk problems - smartctl 0x2002 status

Tags: hard-drive, performance-monitoring, nvme

My NVMe disk works but it is very slow compared to what it was. I benchmarked it 6 months ago at 2000MB/s using fio, the exact same test now is giving me 350MB/s

I ran smartctl but it's giving a 0x2002 status.

Is my disk broken? Can it be repaired or do I need to buy a new one?

```
$ sudo smartctl -A /dev/nvme0n1p2
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-5.0.0-37-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
Read NVMe SMART/Health Information failed: NVMe Status 0x2002

$
```

Comment: You tried to run `smartctl` on a partition rather than the disk.

Comment: that is partition, also ran on nvme0n1, same

Answer (score 1):

The SMART status may not be available for the namespace (`n1`) or partition (`p2`). Hence you must call it for the device itself:

```
smartctl -x /dev/nvme0
```

You can override the namespace to be queried for with `-d nvme,$nsid`, and `0xffffffff` is the "broadcast namespace id". By default `smartctl` selects `$nsid` from the device node namespace id (in your case `1`).
So to query with broadcast:

```
smartctl -x -d nvme,0xffffffff /dev/nvme0n1p2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this:
sudo smartctl -a /dev/nvme0

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
smartctl -d nvme,0xffffffff -x /dev/nvme0n1
```